# Filename in R. Very basic

Tags: r, file, filenames

I am more of a Matlab person, so this question might be too naive, but help will be appreciated.

So in brief, I have a dataset and an R file that already has commands for everything. The instructor said we just need to change the file name in our commands and make it matching this one, so I tried using pracfa and PracticeFA as below:

I replaced the name sdq (which I assume is telling R that this is what I want to call my data file) with pracfa
I replaced the file name ECLSK_SDQ_Demog_subsample.csv with PracticeFA.csv which is the name of the excel sheet we have (please see below)
Then I clicked ctrl + R but the entire command was red, so I could not proceed.

I thought this is likely an easy fix that I can consult stackoverflowers on, then I can see if I can more forward on my own. I am sure after I am past this first part, things will look better.

```
sdq<-read.table("ECLSK_SDQ_Demog_subsample.csv", sep=",", header = TRUE,
 na.strings=c("NA",".","-9","-8","-7","-1"))

pracfa<-read.table("PracticeFA.csv", sep=",", header = TRUE,
 na.strings=c("NA",".","-9","-8","-7","-1"))
```

but it gives me an error, any idea why?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: It would help to know what error it gives.

Comment: Is the read.table giving you errors or something later in the script?  Because if you rename sdq to pracfa then anything that would be expecting an object named sdq wouldn't know what to do...

Comment: pracfa<-read.table("PracticeFA.csv", sep=",", header = TRUE,
+  na.strings=c("NA",".","-9","-8","-7","-1"))

This is the error message that i receive. all in red

Comment: That's not an error message, that's just the command, echoed.